# $.fn or Function.prototype

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this to work.

```
$.fn.createDelegate = function(scope){
var fn = this;
   return function() {
       return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
   }
 }
```

The below version works but I thought they were both the same. The first being a shorthand way of writing the second.
Or maybe I have gotten the idea incorrect.

```
Function.prototype.createDelegate = function(scope){
var fn = this;
   return function() {

       return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
   }
 }
```

When I call the first like this:
     var delegate = this.myMethod.createDelegate(this);
            setTimeout(delegate, 3000);

It says not a function. The second method with Function.prototype works. Can someone explain why and set me straight.

Also would it be best to have this as a small plugin so it doesn't get overwritten thought a large project.

Comment: `$.fn` is for jQuery's prototype, not all Function's prototype.  What is `this.myMethod`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning to `$.fn` will give you a function on the `jQuery` object. jQuery intentionally doesn't touch prototypes of native objects (which is what the second example does). If that style of code appeals you, then you may want to look at [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/).

Comment: So in order to effect the prototype chain you need to use Function.prototype is what your saying. Does this mean $.fn and Jquery.myFunction only effect the dome element or jquery object

Comment: Yes, these will only effect the jQuery object or jQuery collections.

Answer (score 3):

`$.fn` is a shorthand for `jQuery.prototype`, used for adding methods to jQuery selections. It is *not* a shorthand for `Function.prototype`.  You can, however, use the built in jQuery function [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) which will do what you want, I think.

You would do something like this:

```
var delegate = $.proxy(this.myMethod, this);
var delegate = $.proxy(this, 'myMethod'); // slightly briefer but less explicit syntax
```

Comment: Perfect proxy is exactly what I'm after. So in the case of the above so I understand it. Lets say I wasn't using proxy but I still wanted to use my method. How could I apply this a util like function that all methods could use. Would I use Jquery.createDelegate() or I would have to stick to Function.prototype

Comment: @Chapsterj Not sure I understand the question... Can you provide an example?

Comment: You could use the example I first posted. So lets say there was no proxy in Jquery then how would I implement my method to allow it to act like proxy. as in selector.createDelegate(this)